# How do I setup a VPN service like “hide my ass” using Azure?

Tags: vpn, azure

I already subscribe to Microsoft Azure. I would like to know if there's a way to setup a VPN service on Azure to act like a free "Hide My Ass" service that I run?

Just to be clear, it's just for accessing content like Netflix USA.

Any tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to set up a VPN connection through Azure. By default the VPN connection will route all your computer's traffic through the VPN connection while you're connected. This can be changed within the VPN properties from your computer.

Here's a good article explaining the process: http://www.cloudcomputingadmin.com/articles-tutorials/windows-azure/configure-client-based-remote-access-vpn-windows-azure-virtual-networks.html

Comment: I tried playing Netflix while I forgot I was connected to my Azure SSTP VPN and Netflix caught it and did not stream the content. It gave a warning that I was using a proxy or unblocker.

Comment: the link is not active anymore, I could't find the content.