# Change my Ip address using Azure VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, azure

I want to use another IP address for browsing in certain websites. I know for that purpose can be used a VPN, so I started searching about it using Azure as service, because I have an account there. I want to implement my own VPN using Azure. But I cannot understand whether this is possible.

Also I know that there is a lot of free VPN services that can achieve the same with just typing username and password.

In Azure I've created a `Virtual network` with subnet, `Virtual gateway` and configured the point to site (P2S) connection with certificate. It allows to download a `VPN client`, then I install it and connect to it successfully. The advantage that I can gain is that I can ping VM and other devices inside that virtual network. (source: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-resource-manager-portal)

When I type `ipconfig` I see my wireless adapter and another one for the VPN adapter. The last one uses VPN's ipV4 address. I want to use this address while browsing.

Here is another article with clues that this is possible ([How do I setup a VPN service like “hide my ass” using Azure?](https://superuser.com/questions/802976/how-do-i-setup-a-vpn-service-like-hide-my-ass-using-azure))

I found that question [point-to-site vpn connections not changing public ip - azure vnet](https://superuser.com/questions/1240509/point-to-site-vpn-connections-not-changing-public-ip-azure-vnet) .

I executed all of the scripts listed in that article [force tunneling](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-forced-tunneling-rm). I have a `local network gateways` and few connections, but now I cannot understand how can I use it to connect from my PC to the infrastructure that I've created.

I watched few youtube videos and tutorials from Azure academy, but still cannot understand how to "hide my ip address".

Can anyone give a more details is that possible and how to do this in Azure?

Comment: Which IP address do you want to hide?

Comment: Mine, from my laptop at home

Answer (score 0):

When you use the Azure VPN to connect to Azure VM, there will be a tunnel from your PC to the Azure Vnet which your VM in. And it does not change your public IP.

You will know if you know the NAT rules that it would change your laptop IP into your public IP and go to the Internet. And the same as Azure.

You can use your private IP connect to Azure VM because it set up a tunnel between your laptop and Azure Vnet and it still goes through the Internet.

Comment: I've checked the `Radius VPN` configuration in Azure - but it's more complicated that I thought. My router has an option where I set VPN address and put username and password (similar to the "Radius" configuration), but I couldn't set up the Radius Auth Server

Comment: If you use the Azure virtual network gateway, there is a little configuration you can set up. Do you use third-party VPN software?

Comment: No, I want to use Azure only.

Comment: If so, you just can set that what you have seen.